# Can the environment variables tool in Windows be launched directly?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Is there a more direct way to the environmental variables GUI than the following?

1. Right click 'My Computer' and select 'Properties'.
2. Click 'Advanced System Settings' link.
3. Click 'Advanced' tab.
4. Click 'Environment Variables...' button.

Can I make a shortcut to it?

Comment: You can always use "set" (without the quotes) from a command prompt to display, set, or remove environment variables. It doesn't get any more direct than that.

Comment: Using the `set` command will only alter the copy of the environment local to the current command shell. The environment variables in the GUI will hold for all new shells and environments.

Comment: Isn't there [a `shell:` shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/395015/how-to-open-the-recycle-bin-from-the-windows-command-line/395140#395140), like for, for example, the *Recycle Bin*?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Starting with [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), the panel can be displayed from the command line (*cmd.exe*) with a

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

It is [from here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/environment_variables.html).

Comment: beautiful! down with the mouse!

Comment: Even better: [run it from PowerShell](https://gist.github.com/refactorsaurusrex/4cce03f6fe714db533d6c7bcb5a57444)!

Comment: If you want to open the Windows Environment Variables dialog from a launcher application such as SlickRun, you can enter `cmd` as the command, and `/c "start rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables"` as the parameters. This will open cmd.exe, open the Environment Variables dialog, and immediately close the cmd.exe window that was just opened. I have this mapped to the `env` keyword in SlickRun, so I can quickly view Windows environment variables using the standard Unix `env` command. (And I have SlickRun run this as admin so I can edit system-level environment variables.)

Comment: Windows10 Update: If you want to run this command in Windows 10 the syntax has changed just a bit: `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables` (courtesy of [this site](https://winaero.com/create-environment-variables-shortcut-windows-10/) )

Answer (score 12):

I recommend this: Open the "Run" prompt → type "SystemPropertiesAdvanced". You will be on the *Advanced* tab of the *System Properties* window. From here it's easy. I feel this is an easier command to remember than the command prompt's and a good shortcut.

[Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7): Start menu → in the search bar, type "system variables" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will have the *Advanced* tab of the system properties window open.

[Windows 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8) and later: Simply type the above in the search box in the task bar.

Comment: This required Admin access on a peer's computer.  The accepted answer did not.

Comment: It should be the Accepted Answer.

Comment: If your logged in account is an Administrator account, you won't have the UAC prompt with this method (on Win 10 20H2). The "rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables" method won't let you change the system environment variables unless you run it as Administrator which shows an UAC prompt. But you arrive directly on the right window.

Answer (score 5):

Open [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29), copy the below line, and save it as "SysPropAdv.bat". Run in a *cmd* prompt. It will open a system properties window.

start SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe

Comment: that is also good but not the great to reached till environment variable . thanks

Comment: or in a different way use -> window + r -> and type SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe -> and just enter, making .bat and finding to file and double click may not be the efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with an **administrator's rights** (to be able to edit the **System Variables**):

- from the "Run" command prompt, use:

  ```
  powershell -command "&{start-process rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables -verb RunAs}
  ```
- from the cmd shell, use:

  ```
  start powershell -command "&{start-process rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables -verb RunAs}"
  ```

Comment: On Windows 10 20H2, the SystemPropertiesAdvanced method does not prompt for administrator privileges if your account is an Administrator.

Comment: You can also add `-WindowStyle hidden` before `-command`  to minimize the powershell window.